# Using Page Breaks in Card Layout

Tags: css, google-fusion-tables, page-break

I am trying to use the cards layout in fusion tables to generate a report. I have customized the layout of the cards but I am having trouble figuring out how to size the cards so that they each fit on a letter sized page when you go to the 'publish' view. Right now, when I try to print, page breaks are happening in the middle of divs.

I know there are some CSS methods for doing this but Im wondering if I could insert the right tags/styles within the custom layout dialog or do I have to create a separate web-page.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late news, but you can now use "page-break-inside: avoid" in your CSS to reduce page breaks in cards.